# Share bandwidth between Linodes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, load-balancing, linode

I have 5 linode instances, most of them are in moderate use.

Recently I opened a site that takes up a lot of bandwidth, and the linode that its on is being hammered with traffic spending my precious few gb's I have allocated to that linode (200GB/month).

Is there any way to set up the same site on all instances and share the bandwidth? Sort of like a load balancer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linode [pools your quota](http://blog.linode.com/2010/02/08/bandwidth-pooling/):

> While we’ve had network
>   transfer/bandwidth pooling in our
>   internal accounting for some time,
>   it’s never been displayed in the
>   Linode Manager — until now.  At the
>   bottom of the main Linodes tab, you’ll
>   now see a new section that displays
>   the cumulative network transfer quotas
>   for all your Linodes for this month,
>   how much you’ve used, and how much is
>   remaining.

As a Linode customer, I can confirm that the bandwidth is pooled.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to ask the Linode guys to be certain, but I'm fairly sure that bandwidth is pooled for all linodes on a single account. Give them a call and ask - they have *great* tech support.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the kind of site, but if you can host the same site across multiple instances you can setup DNS round robin answers so that when people lookup to connect to the site they get a random answer from DNS about what IP to talk to. This will even things out a little bit, but you have to make sure your site software is prepared for the multiple-host environment it will end up being in. User generated data becomes tricky to handle.

Comment: My site is  PHP/Mysql based, so maybe i can have the mysql db on one of the linodes and interlink them using the linode private network. also, i just read the wikipedia page for the 'DNS Round Robin'. Looks like it has a lot of drawbacks, any other way of doing this?

Comment: Any "sort of like the real thing" solution is going to have drawbacks, but that's specifically what you asked for. Also, if your data is coming from a database is having different servers serve the data but having them all transfer data from a single database server actually going to help your quota?